# Is it better to use 512 MB RAM of AVD while using Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I started using Android Studio and when I run AVD it runs sometimes and sometimes it shows `session :error installing APK` after gradle binding.It works fine when I use `Build APK`.

So Is the problem with the AVD RAM 1GB size. Is it better to change to 512MB RAM so that it runs successfully?

My system specifications are 4GB RAM,intel i3 processor,windows 10.

What is the solution to run successfully,should I change the system?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like 1GB of memory or less is what is needed to run AVD properly. So the problem stems from the amount of RAM you have/are using.

According to this post [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124089/avd-is-not-able-to-launch) you should select your device in the AVD manager and click "Edit". In memory options find the RAM parameter and set it to lower than 1GB (i.e. less than 1024 MB)

Check the post I linked to for more information. I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Dont use emulator, its slow and buggy. I suggest you to use genymotion emulator , with this you can execute your code way faster and also you can choose from so many virtual devices. download genymotion from here https://www.genymotion.com Also its camera works very fine. Its android plugin for android studio will help you run it on a single click.